# Nuget from portable class library: Value cannot be null or an empty string. Parameter name: profileValue

Tags: nuget, portable-class-library, .net-4.6, nuspec

### What I have

I have Portable Class Library `MyProj.Backend.Contracts.csproj` with following

project.json:

```
{
  "supports": {
    "net46.app": {},
    "uwp.10.0.app": {},
    "dnxcore50.app": {}
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.NETCore": "5.0.0",
    "Microsoft.NETCore.Portable.Compatibility": "1.0.0",
    "NuSpec.ReferenceGenerator": "1.4.2"
  },
  "frameworks": {
    "dotnet": {
      "imports": "portable-net452+win81"
    }
  }
}
```

and nuspec:

```
<package xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/packaging/2012/06/nuspec.xsd">
  <metadata>
    <id>MyProj.Backend.Contracts</id>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <dependencies>
      <group targetFramework="dotnet">
        <dependency id="System.Resources.ResourceManager" version="4.0.0" />
        <dependency id="System.Runtime" version="4.0.20" />
      </group>
  </metadata>
</package>
```

Notice, that I've added NuSpec.ReferenceGenerator to my project, that added '' to my project json.

However, I'm still not able to pack my PCL library:

```
 nuget pack MyProj.Backend.Contracts.csproj
```

```
  Attempting to build package from 'MyProj.Backend.Contracts.csproj'.
  Packing files from 'C:\Projects\MyProj\Backend\Contracts\Dev\bin\Contracts'.
  Using ''MyProj.Backend.Contracts.csproj.nuspec' for metadata.
  Value cannot be null or an empty string.
  Parameter name: profileValue
```

### What I need

How to modify my .nuspec so I can create package from my PCL library project?

Answer (score 5):

This is an issue with the new project.json and specifying dependencies. The error message is pretty bad but there is some guidance on how to make this work here: https://github.com/ericstj/NuGetDocs/blob/ericstj/nuget3samples/NuGet.Docs/Create/nuget3-packages-walkthrough.md

The short answer seems to be to use the Nuget package nuspec.referencegenerator to fill out the nuspec file correctly for you.

Just to add in reference to the comments below; with Nuget 3.3 (haven't tested with 3.4 or higher), mixing csproj and project.json files just doesn't seem to work (or it only works for a subset of scenarios). If you want to use a project.json you seem to need to use the new json project format for code files, or vice versa revert to a standard nuspec and csproj combination.

Comment: I've tried to add this package and also play a little with my nuspec but I'm still getting the same error

Comment: nuspec.referencegenerator is not supposed to make csproj packing to work. It helps to add dependencies to nuspec in each build or by command line

Comment: While the situation may have changed for the recent 3.4 release, attempting to use a project.json with a csproj really doesn't seem to work. I tried for a cross platform package and reverted to the csproj and nuspec method. As far as I can see, if you want to use project.json you need to be using the new project format for your code files as well.